# What does use crate::body::Body; mean?

Tags: rust, module

On https://github.com/sdroege/rtsp-server/blob/master/src/listener/message_socket.rs, it does

```
use crate::body::Body;
```

I could only find information about external crates: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/extern-crates.html

What does `use crate::` mean?

Comment: Its explained in [The Rust Reference: Paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#crate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It refers to to the crate currently being compiled. So in this example, it is resolved as `rtsp_server::body::Body`. The `body::Body` part is refering to the `Body` item in the `body` module.

The [Rust documentation says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.crate.html):

> `crate` is also used to represent the absolute path of a module, where `crate` refers to the
> root of the current crate. For instance, `crate::foo::bar` refers to the name `bar` inside the
> module `foo`, from anywhere else in the same crate.